# ES6 Array of functions, trouble with this

Tags: arrays, function, ecmascript-6, binding, this

I'm trying to understand why my this binding doesn't work in the following example.
The expected output is:
NEXT, FUNC-01, 1, NEXT, etc. etc.

Instead, I'm getting an error "can't read property 'counter' of undefined", which means I'm losing the this binding.  I don't understand how to retain that binding.  Here's the code:

```
class NotWorkingThing {
constructor () {
    this.nextArray = [
        this.func01,
        this.func02,
        this.func03
    ];

    this.counter = 0;
}

next () {
    console.log("NEXT");
    const nextFunction = this.nextArray.shift();
    nextFunction().bind(this);
};

func01 () {
    console.log("FUNC-01");
    this.counter ++;
    console.log(this.counter);
    this.next();
};

func02 () {
    console.log("FUNC-02");
    this.counter ++;
    console.log(this.counter);
    this.next();
};

func03 () {
    console.log("FUNC-03");
    this.counter ++;
    console.log(this.counter);
    this.next();
};
}


const thing = new NotWorkingThing();
thing.next();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind is a method of a function, and it returns a function which can be called afterwards. The correct code would be

```
class NotWorkingThing {
constructor() {
this.nextArray = [
  this.func01,
  this.func02,
  this.func03
];
this.counter = 0;
}
next() {
console.log("NEXT");
const nextFunction = this.nextArray.shift();
if (!nextFunction) return;
const nextFunctionWithBind = nextFunction.bind(this);
nextFunctionWithBind();
};
func01() {
console.log("FUNC-01");
this.counter++;
console.log(this.counter);
this.next();
};

func02() {
console.log("FUNC-02");
this.counter++;
console.log(this.counter);
this.next();
};
func03() {
console.log("FUNC-03");
this.counter++;
console.log(this.counter);
this.next();
};
}
 const thing = new NotWorkingThing();
thing.next();
```

Comment: I was so confused by this.  Thank you.  Is it possible to do the same thing using arrow functions inside the class body (assuming babel is configured properly), because they don't have a "this" binding?